# Recover admin password and email Odoo server

Tags: email, passwords, odoo, recover

Months ago, I installed an Odoo server and it worked perfectly !

Problem is that I forgot the identification (email/pass) for the admin, wich is real bad.
After uninstalling the server and reinstalling it I found out that the database was not wiped. So it didn't change at all !

Please, can anyone help me finding the admin's **email** **and** **password** ?

I'm not very familiar with progresql but *res_users* displays empty passwords:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may change admin password using progresql from the terminal. You just need to do like these

```
odoo@odedra:~$ psql testing_db
psql (9.1.14)
Type "help" for help.

testing_db=# UPDATE res_users SET password='new_password' WHERE login = 'admin';
UPDATE 1
```

where *testing_db* is database name.

Now login with new password and change user details whatever you want.

Comment: password column becomes empty when we install auth_crypt module also. so updating password with new_password will not work

Comment: You need to update the password_crypt filed in the database with the crypt of the password. Just updateding the plaintext password field won't work

Answer (score 7):

You need to generate password with pbkdf2_sha512 hashing algorithm. Then update the record id = 1 with password_crypt field not password.

For example:

- Generating hash from python code:

  `from passlib.context import CryptContext`

  `print CryptContext(['pbkdf2_sha512']).encrypt('<PASSOWORD>')`
- Then:

  `update res_users set password='' ,password_crypt='<HASH>' where id = <ID>;`

Replace ,  with the generated output from the script and designated id.