# How to log in to odoo after creating a database?

Tags: macos, postgresql, odoo

The requirements for odoo 9 are successfully installed. I'm vaulting the software from the source directory without installing it using the command

```
./openerp-server -r <USER> -w <PASSWORD> --db_port 5432 -d <DATABASE>
```

When I first ran the command as postgres user, the browser at the address `localhost:8069` asked me to create a new database with a database name (although I already gave `DATABASE` as `mydb` in the command line above) using an admin user password. I gave `odootest` as database name along with the admin password (postgres user password) and checked the load demonstration data checkbox. The new instance was created and the list of apps were displayed. Everything was fine till that point

After logging out, I'm unable to log back in as the screen now shows this

[image]

I don't remember giving any email id with a password for this. How am I supposed to log in now? Is there any default entry for this?

OS: Mac OS-X 10.9

Comment: might be useful in future http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557208/recover-admin-password-and-email-odoo-server/27560618

Comment: @Odedra: Thanks for the added info. This surely ought to be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use in every OS

```
user: admin
psw: admin
```

it's default for all odoo/openerp version

Comment: Thank you. Just one exception: the password was what I gave for the odoo user, but the email id (specified as user in your post) was indeed admin.